# Dividir por 100 y truncar a dos decimales el resultado

Tags: sql, sqlite

Tengo una tabla con sector, meses, año y ventas. Quiero agrupar por sector, meses y año obteniendo así la suma de ventas y el resultado de esta agrupación dividirlo por 100 y truncarlo a dos decimales. Cómo puedo hacerlo?

De momento tengo esto:

```
select year, month, sector, amount/100 
from categories 
group by year, month, sector
```

Por el momento estoy trabajando con SQLite(https://sqliteonline.com/). Sé que no es lo más óptimo pero por el momento creo que no necesito más.

Comment: qué tipo de dato es la columna `amount`?

Comment: Es un decimal. @Lamak

Comment: simplemente usa `SUM(amount/100)`

Comment: La Suma ya la hace agrupando por las demás columnas. Lo que no sé es integrar en la consulta el truncado a dos decimales principalmente. @Lamak

Answer (score 3):

Primeramente es importante tener en cuenta que SQLite es muy particular con respecto a los tipos de datos.

Si lees el apartado [*2. Storage Classes and Datatypes*](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storage_classes_and_datatypes) en  la documentación verás lo siguiente (la traducción es mía, y he puesto algunas negritas a propósito para este caso):

> Cada valor almacenado en una base de datos SQLite (o manipulado por el
> motor de la base de datos) tiene una de las siguientes clases de
> almacenamiento:
>
> - **`NULL`**. El valor es un valor NULO.
> - **`INTEGER`**. El valor es un entero con signo, almacenado en 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 u 8 bytes según la magnitud del valor.
> - **`REAL`**. El valor es un valor de punto flotante, almacenado como un número de punto flotante IEEE de 8 bytes.
> - **`TEXT`**. El valor es una cadena de texto, almacenada usando la codificación de la base de datos (UTF-8, UTF-16BE o UTF-16LE).
> - **`BLOB`**. El valor es una masa de datos, almacenada exactamente como se ingresó.
>
> Una **clase de almacenamiento** es más general que un tipo de datos.
> La clase de almacenamiento `INTEGER`, por ejemplo, incluye 6 tipos de
> datos enteros diferentes de diferentes longitudes. Esto marca la
> diferencia en el disco. Pero tan pronto como los valores `INTEGER` se
> leen del disco y se almacenan en la memoria para su procesamiento,
> **se convierten al tipo de datos más general** (entero con signo de 8 bytes). Y así, en su mayor parte, "clase de almacenamiento" es
> indistinguible de "tipo de datos" y los dos términos se pueden usar
> indistintamente.
>
> Cualquier columna en una base de datos SQLite versión 3, excepto una
> columna INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, puede usarse para almacenar un valor de
> cualquier clase de almacenamiento.
>
> Todos los valores de las sentencias SQL, ya sean literales incrustados
> en el texto de la sentencia SQL o parámetros vinculados a sentencias
> SQL precompiladas tienen una clase de almacenamiento implícita. En las
> circunstancias que se describen a continuación, **el motor de la base
> de datos puede convertir valores entre clases de almacenamiento
> numérico (`INTEGER` y `REAL`) y `TEXT` durante la ejecución de la
> consulta**.

En una base de datos tradicional, lo propio en tu caso sería hacer un `CAST` de todo el valor resultante a `DECIMAL` (o  a cualquier otro tipo que necesites), pero SQLite no soporta `DECIMAL` y los eventuales valores decimales resultantes de la división entre dos enteros se perderían ([ver las reglas de conversión](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr)).

Por tanto, simplemente puedes castear el operando a `REAL` y el resultado será el esperado.

Y, para mostrar dos posiciones decimales, puedes valerte de `printf`:

```
select 
    year, 
    month, 
    sector, 
    printf("%.2f",cast(sum(amount) as real)/100) as div
from categories 
group by year, month, sector
```

La clave de todo es **forzar a alguno de los valores a `REAL`** lo cual hace que SQLite aplique una regla de conversión adecuada en la que los valores decimales no se pierdan.

Por ejemplo, puedes optar por poner el operador como un valor de tipo `REAL` (`100.00`) y verás que también funciona (en este caso no hay conversión del operando):

```
select 
    year, 
    month, 
    sector, 
    printf("%.2f",sum(amount)/100.00) as div
from categories 
group by year, month, sector
```

Comment: +1, muy buena respuesta, pero faltaría el `sum` en `amount`

Comment: Gracias @Lamak. He agregado SUM(), aunque la respuesta de OP a tu comentario hace pensar que no pretende usar SUM() ¿? Por eso no lo puse inicialmente.

Answer (score 1):

```
select year, month, sector, printf("%.2f", sum(amount)/100) as ventas
from categorias
group by year, month, sector;
```

Esta consulta agrupa por los campos especificados y en la **cláusula** **select** se utiliza la **función** **printf** para dar formato de dos decimales al número obtenido de la suma de las **ventas/100**. **".2f"** indica que se mostrará un número con dos decimales.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no existe una función para truncar un número en SQLite, pero puedes multiplicar por la potencia N de 10, donde N es el número de decimales, después conviertes a entero y dividir entre ese número.

```
select year, month, sector, cast((SUM(amount)/100.0 * 100) as int) / 100.0
from categories 
group by year, month, sector
```